What to prepare for if I want to add CSI CMOS cameras to my Auvidea Carrier board with Jetson Xavier
I am new to embedded development. I have an Auvidea JNX30D development board with a Jetson Xavier NX on it. I want to use CSI CMOS cameras with this system. The board has 2 CSI links which I can use. The Auvidea BSP comes with dtb files for a few sensors like IMX219. My question is, if I want to use other cameras (also CSI), how to make it work? DO I have to write my own driver? I know very little about all this. Just looking for a few helpful hints.
